# how to get current time as 00/00/0000 00:00:00 with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello i want to get current time as 00/00/0000 00:00:00 with javascript ?

```
00/00/0000 00:00:00
```

is it possible or must to use a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();

console.log(`${date.toLocaleDateString()} ${date.toLocaleTimeString()}`);
```

Comment: i only want 00/00/0000 00:00:00

Comment: date.toLocaleDateString   gets date with format like this - dd/mm/yyyy 
and date.toLocaleTimeString gets date with format like - hr/minute/sec

Comment: oh i forgot parenthees

Comment: please check the update

Answer (score 0):

Plain JavaScript provides the Date() object which returns that information.

```
var date=new Date();
console.log(date);
```

If you want it to look exactly like

**00/00/0000 00:00:00**

you can format it yourself using this:

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds());
```

Comment: not worked get : Tue Mar 12 2019 20:59:52 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00) i only want 00/00/0000 00:00:00

Comment: My bad - I refined my answer.